# How does Starfire know she's a diminutive female as opposed to a normal sized female?

Tags: dc, teen-titans-go

An episode of *Teen Titans Go!* which involves stories about old timey fables has Starfire as some girl going to give a basket of food or something to her gran.

She eats a wolf or something and in the episode she says that she is a diminutive female, how does she know (or think) that she is small when her friends are all smaller then her except Cyborg?

Comment: What about other people she may have seen?  I haven't seen Teen Titans in years, but don't they live in a populated world?

Answer (score 6):

She's not describing *herself* as small, she's describing the protagonist of the classic story (AKA "***Little*** Red Riding Hood") as being small.

> **Starfire:** Oh, oh, oh! Oh, the story of **the diminutive female who wore the red cloak of the riding**. I am quite familiar with this tale of the folk.

which boils down to

> *"Ah, the story of **Little** Red Riding Hood. I know this folk tale"*